# ODBC Permission Error from MS Access DB despite having the necessary DB grants

Tags: oracle, ms-access, odbc

[image]
User, XX has the delete grants on a Oracle DB table.
XX can delete the record from the table directly upon connecting to DB via TOAD/SQL Dev/...

XX cannot delete the same record from the same table when accessing it as a linked table from MS Access DB.

Error:

```
ODBC - delete on a linked table failed.
ORA - 01031: insufficient privileges
```

Same is the case when trying to delete the record either from a custom form or from the linked table row.

User can however read, insert data through the linked table.
User can also delete the record from another linked table with the delete privileges.

Things tried so far:

1. Deleting the linked table and relinking it.
2. Re-configuring the ODBC.
3. Removed and provided the table specific grants again.
4. Verified that all the action triggers and Access macros are not causing any access issue.

Any thoughts/inputs will be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try deleting the linked table in Access and re-linking it?

Comment: normally to be able to delete (or update) a record from a linked table MsAccess requires a unique index (or primary key) on the table, do you have one? Admittedly your error message indicates that it is Oracle rejecting it; so are you sure that, when you linked the table, you didn't provide a username/password for the database login and that user (as opposed to the one you use inTOAD etc) has the privileges?

Comment: @deluxeinformation Yes, i did. Updated the notes. Thanks.

Comment: @tinazmu Thanks
1. Yes, the table has a primary key i.e. 'Option ID'.
2. As per the process, all the tables are linked using a service/schema account of the DB in which user has privileges too. This has been the practice being followed over years.
3. If Oracle is rejecting it, wondering why the user is able to delete the record when accessing the DB directly (through TOAD) without MS-Access and yes, DB, Username password are same.
Please let me know if i didn't clarify your question above.

Comment: Do you have a trigger on the table that causes another table to be affected?

Comment: @dbmitch There is a trigger that inserts data into a different table for audit purpose but the user has necessary grants on that as well. And as the delete in the DB(if user logs into DB and executes DELETE FROM.... statement) directly works without any issues, i am sure all is good at the DB end. There is something weird with respect to the ODBC call happening from ACCESS to the DB.